# Viewport zoom vs dolly

Tags: camera

What is the difference between zooming in the viewport using the wheel on the mouse and dollying using shift ctrl mmb?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DNR: Dolly-Zoom is exactly the same as Zoom In-Out but allows you to move the view point.

It has nothing to do with the photographic use of *zoom* and *dolly*

Zoom shortcuts call [`view3d.zoom`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.view3d.html#bpy.ops.view3d.zoom) and dolly shortcuts call [`view3d.dolly`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.view3d.html#bpy.ops.view3d.dolly), but the documentation is next to useless.

The actual difference can be found by examining [Zoom In-Out](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/navigate/navigation.html#zoom-in-out) and [Dolly Zoom](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/navigate/navigation.html#dolly-zoom) in the *Navigation* section of the manual:

> In most cases its sufficient to zoom the view to get a closer look at something, however, you may notice that at a certain point you cannot zoom any closer.
>
> This is because Blender stores a view-point that is used for orbiting and zooming. It works well in many cases, but sometimes you want to move the view-point to a different place. This is what *Dolly supports, allowing you to transport the view from one place to another.* [emphasis mine.]

Answer (score 2):

According to the wikipedia "camera dolly" entry :

> A camera dolly is a wheeled cart or similar device used in filmmaking
> and television production to create **smooth** horizontal camera movements

(emphasis mine)

So you can consider the mouse wheel "zoom" as a dolly with fixed, discrete, locations, and a clear cut maximal distance it can travel from the origin point before needing to be reset. But it's not technically a zoom since the viewport camera focal length doesn't change at any point.

Both do the same thing. But the "dolly" zoom controls more smoothly, and you need to hold down 3 buttons at the same time and move the mouse which is not very user-friendly (arguably).

Comment: As far as I can tell both zoom and dolly are equally smooth

Comment: Maybe there is a misunderstanding on the term then, because when you use just the mouse wheel, the viewport camera "jumps" forward a bit, contrary to when using the CTRL SHIFT MMB one where it moves forward quasi-seamlessly

Comment: You can also use ctrl mmb which zooms in and out as smoothly as using ctrl shift mmb to dolly

Comment: Oh, right, I didn't notice that. In that case I really don't know what's the difference at first glance

Comment: The reason why one zooms smoothly and the other doesn't is that the shortcuts for one have `delta` set but the shortcut for the other doesn't.  The commands themselves are identical with respect to smoothness.