# Zoom View - Delta parameter

Tags: navigation

I would like to ask what the "Delta" parameter in the "view3d.zoom" operator is responsible for?
Changing this value doesn't seem to make any changes to the zooming in and out process.
Thanks.

[image]

Comment: See the very last comment from Marty Fouts here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/264055/viewport-zoom-vs-dolly. That's the only information I can find anywhere about it!